# How to instal Aegir without root access

Tags: aegir

The Aegir documentation states that root access is required for installation, but I have seen comments suggesting it is possible to instal without root.
If this is correct can anyone point me in the right direction?

Background:
I host a few non profit sites with an Aegir service provider who has provided great service. But the sites have grown and the cost has become a challenge for them. I don't have the skills for a self-managed server, so I am hoping to be able to find someone to instal on a fully managed server where someone else can maintain it and keep it secure etc.

Answer (score 2):

> The Aegir documentation states that root access is required for
> installation, but I have seen comments suggesting it is possible to
> instal without root. If this is correct can anyone point me in the
> right direction?

In addition to the installation and configuration of web and database servers, the standard installation of Aegir requires the creation of a user account and the deployment of one or more `sudoers` files.

While I'm sure there are creative ways to work around some of this, each step down that path gets you further and further from a standard setup. The more bespoke your deployment becomes the more time and effort will be required to ensure its security and reliability.

I highly recommend against pursing this path.

> I host a few non profit sites with an Aegir service provider who has
> provided great service. But the sites have grown and the cost has
> become a challenge for them.

Have you offered to cover the costs for your current Aegir service provider to scale up their hardware, move your sites to a dedicated server, etc.? This is likely to be the most cost-effective approach, since they're presumably already tooled up for the deployment and management of Aegir servers.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, especially about avoiding a non-standard setup.. I'm talking to a couple of service providers who may be able to help.